# POST File Upload Request using Base64

Tags: c#, api, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am creating a task in a third party application using the clients  web api. I can create the task and distribute all around but now i have been stuck with Uploading a file to the third party application.

They have not given me too much information regarding how their api handles this POST. Instead they showed me how the 200 OK response will be.

I tried something new now and decided to use Restsharp in my library.

When i upload a file i am not sure how to upload the actual file, i am successfully converting it to base64, and want to know where in the request body will i put the base64, if it is even possible.

The third party application does create a file in the task, but is has 0 bytes, as the request is not pointing to a file.

I have already tried seperating the parameters so that i don't use the string, but the one dev recommended trying it.

I have also tried creating a formupload class and then referencing it to upload the file. Code can be supplied if needed.

```
            /* Greate uniqueGuid for EntityID */
            Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            string EntityID = guid.ToString();
            // string val = guid.ToString();
            // EntityID = "\"" + val + "\"";
            SetTokenValue("uniqueGuid", EntityID);

            var client = new 
            RestClient("https://www.notallowed.com/media");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

            bearerToken = TokenReplace("%(BearerToken)");
            if (bearerToken != null)
            {
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken);
                SetTokenValue("PDF_Token", bearerToken);
            }

            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("accept", "*/*; q=0.5, application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
            request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"EntityType\"\r\n\r\npredistributed-tasks\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"EntityId\"\r\n\r\n"+ EntityID +"\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"LocaleIsoCode\"\r\n\r\nen-US\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"files\";  filename=\"UntitledContract.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;
            int numericCode = (int) statusCode;
            SetTokenValue("PDF_StatusCode", numericCode);

            request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json";};
```

My expected results is to have the file parameter point to a physical file and have it use that file and upload it to the task created.

The actual output is that no file is actually being uploaded instead the third party application is creating a placeholder for the file.